# Error while passing dataframe to UDF in Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming, pyspark

I am reading events from Kafka in Spark Structured streaming and need to process events one by one and write to redis. I wrote a UDF for that but it gives me spark context error.

```
conf = SparkConf()\
.setAppName(spark_app_name)\
.setMaster(spark_master_url)\
.set("spark.redis.host", "redis")\
.set("spark.redis.port", "6379")\
.set("spark.redis.auth", "abc")

spark = SparkSession.builder\
.config(conf=conf)\
.getOrCreate()

def func(element, event, timestamp):
    #redis i/o
    pass

schema = ArrayType(StructType(
[
    StructField("element_id", StringType()),
    StructField("event_name", StringType()),
    StructField("event_time", StringType())
]
))

df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", topic) \
    .load()
    #.option("includeTimestamp", value = True)\

ds = df.selectExpr(("CAST(value AS STRING)"))\
     .withColumn("value", explode(from_json("value", schema)))

filter_func = udf(func, ArrayType(StringType()))

ds = ds.withColumn("column_name", filter_func(
    ds['value']['element_id'], 
    ds['value']['event_name'], 
    ds['value']['event_time']
))

query = ds.writeStream \
        .format("console") \
        .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Error message: _pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you also add this - update_nfa ??

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: updated with error message

Comment: do you need an array?

Comment: Yes, the udf function returns a list of strings but I could not find a ListType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to access spark context from within user defined function which is not allowed.
Within the udf, I was trying to write to spark-redis by using spark context.